# Exceptions in C# not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, exception

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API for my React front end app.

My problem is that my exceptions are not trickling up through my object hierarchy as I expect. I think it might be due to some multi-threading issue, but I don't know enough about C# to be sure! I am learning on Pluralsight, but I'm currently studying networking, which is not going to help me with this!

The calling code is a SignalR Hub method, that looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateProfile(object profileDto)
{
  try
  {
    ProfileDTO profile = ((JsonElement) profileDto).ToObject<ProfileDTO>();
    _profile.UpdateProfile(profile);
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I would expect that any exceptions thrown or not handled in `_profile.UpdateProfile(profile);` would cause the exception block here to return false. My `UpdateProfile()` looks like this:

```
public void UpdateProfile(ProfileDTO profileDto)
{
  _databaseService.ExecuteInTransaction(async session =>
  {
    // simulate an error
    throw new Exception("Some exception");
  });
}
```

...and my `ExecuteInTransaction()` looks like this:

```
public async void ExecuteInTransaction(Func<IClientSessionHandle, Task> databaseAction)
{
  using var session = await Client.StartSessionAsync();

  try
  {
    session.StartTransaction();
    await databaseAction(session);
    await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I would expect that the exception thrown in `UpdateProfile()` would trickle up to the catch block in `ExecuteInTransaction()` — which it does — but then further, I would expect this exception to trickle up to the Hub `UpdateProfile()` method. Instead, it ends up in the `Throw()` method on the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class in the `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices` namespace.

Reading through the comments in this file makes me think it is a threading issue, but I don't know enough about how threading works yet in C#. Is it possible for the exceptions thrown in `UpdateProfile()` to make it up to the top level of my Hub `UpdateProfile()`? (*just noticed they confusingly have the same name*).

Comment: As a side note, use `throw;`, not `throw e;`, so you don't lose the original call stack in the exception.

Comment: Gotchya, ok thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `async void` signature of `ExecuteInTransaction`.

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so **any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started**
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

What this means, if you're using ASP.NET Core where there is no `SynchronizationContext`, your exception will be thrown *most* likely on a threadpool thread if you didn't mess around with the TaskScheduler. If you're on older .NET framework code, it will be on the captured context but either way, what you know about exception handling does not apply here. You can catch these exceptions by subscribing to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` but no one wants to do that in maintainable code.

To fix this, change `public async void ExecuteInTransaction` to `public async Task ExecuteInTransaction`, change `public void UpdateProfile` to `public async Task UpdateProfile` and call it like so:

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdateProfile(object profileDto)
{
  try
  {
    ProfileDTO profile = ((JsonElement) profileDto).ToObject<ProfileDTO>();
    await _profile.UpdateProfile(profile);
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return false;
  }
}

public async Task UpdateProfile(ProfileDTO profileDto)
{
  await _databaseService.ExecuteInTransaction(async session =>
  {
    // simulate an error
    throw new Exception("Some exception");
  });
}
```

Comment: Oo, that fixed it. Remarkable knowledge, thank you!